# type(of: ) in Swift 3 does not seem to work with the is type check

Tags: swift, swift3, typechecking

`type(of: x)` in Swift 3 does not seem to work with the `is` type check

It just gives this error message:

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Code example:

```
class Test : UIViewController {}

let test = Test()
let test2 = Test()
let isEqual = test2 is type(of: test) // this does not compile
```

What is wrong here? 
How to do dynamic type checking like this in Swift 3?

Comment: Could you do `type(of: test2) == type(of: test)`?

Comment: yes - `type(of: test2) == type(of: test)` works, but it is not as clean as with the is operator. But it does the job.

Comment: It sounds like you have an X/Y problem.  Why are you using `is` to check types?  Why not use a conditional downcast (`if let x = y as? Foo { }`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific context:

```
class Test : UIViewController {}

class Test1 : UIViewController {}

let test = Test()
let test2 = Test1()

let f = test2.isKind(of: test2.classForCoder)

print(f)
```

> Output: true

This might be another idea for checking the type

Other than that

```
let q = type(of: test) == type(of: test)
```

Will return true but only if that was the same class not a subclass

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing 2 different incomparable types which won't work unless you have overloaded `==` to handle such

`test2` vs. `type(of: test)`.

---

As Connor commented:

```
print(type(of: test)) // Test
print(test2) // <__lldb_expr_22.Test: 0x7ffe8cb063e0>

let isEqual = type(of:test2) == type(of: test) // true
```

Comment: That would return `true` only for *identical* types, not for instances of a subclass.

Comment: So basically my has 0 value here right ? :) I'm just going to leave the answer here, because of the valuable comment you left. :)